# Why java.lang.Math#cbrt doesn't mention semi-monotonic?

Tags: java, floating-point

I was reading the documents of Math functions, and found cbrt quite strange.

Its precision is only "within 1 ulp", and it doesn't mention "the semi-monotonic thing".

Is it hard give these guarantees for the "cube root" function, or they simply forgot to add these guarantees?

I can imagine "cbrt" to be harder to implemented than "sqrt", so I'm not so surprised it gives "1 ulp" instead of "0.5 ulp". But isn't "the semi-monotonic thing" much easier? In fact most functions in this class have this property.

By the way, does anyone knows whether common JDK implementation exploits this omission? For example, can anyone give me an example, such that, cbrt(x) > cbrt(y) when x < y?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Math#cbrt is delegated to StrictMath#cbrt, which uses fdlibm to cacluated cbrt.

Comments say the precision is about 0.667 ulp, which is within 1 ulp.

I still don't find a single violation of the monotonic property.

I know some libm's cbrt is not monotonic.

This code snippet illustrates this phenomenon.

```
// a.c
// compile with gcc a.c -lm
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double x = 8.000000000000012;
    double y = 8.000000000000014;
    printf("%s\n", (x < y) ? "yes" : "no");
    printf("%s\n", (cbrt(x) < cbrt(y)) ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

On my machine it outputs

```
yes
no
```

**UPDATE**
found a violation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x1 = 1.9998501732312939;
    double x2 = 1.999850173231294;
    System.out.println(x1 < x2);
    System.out.println(Math.cbrt(x1) == Math.cbrt(x2));
    System.out.println(Math.cbrt(x1) < Math.cbrt(x2));
}
```

Comment: @StephenC Why? For most x and y, "cbrt(x) < cbrt(y)" should yield same result as "x < y"

Comment: The definition of **semi-monotonic** from the javadoc is "whenever the mathematical function is non-increasing, so is the floating-point approximation."  Your `(cbrt(x) < cbrt(y)` is not a test for "non-increasing".   That was what I am trying to point out.

Comment: @StephenC You mean they maybe equal? That's correct.

Comment: According to the definition ... yes.